# Converting Kinect IR images to points

Tags: ros, openni, pcl, ir, images

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My goal is to compress a movie of kinect data into the smallest format possible.   I'm investigating if I can use movie compression on either the raw /camera/ir/image_raw images or maybe the /camera/depth_registered/image_raw frames.

I'm using [this tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbag/Tutorials/Exporting%20image%20and%20video%20data) to extract the frames from a rosbag recording.  And it works great.  For the next step, I have two questions:

1. Can you export image frames in png (i.e. a lossless) format for compression?  I found [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/27713/how-to-recover-the-saved-images-in-a-bagfile-to-jpg-or-png/) answer but I'd prefer not use openCV/python.
2. Is there a ros node to convert the raw image format into points.  "convert_pointcloud_to_image" will convert points into images but I'm looking to use both the camera data & the image to get points & haven't found a tutorial or node for this...

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 w/Electric & PCL 1.6, as I haven't had good luck with Openni drivers on 12.04.  Looking in: /opt/ros/electric/stacks/perception_pcl/pcl_ros/bin I don't see anything that does what I would want.  I assume  this functionality exists somewhere (as the Openni drivers converts an inferred image into a point cloud) but I can't seem to find it.

Help please?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45004/converting-kinect-ir-images-to-points/) by [dtj](https://answers.ros.org/users/2288/dtj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2012-10-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I assume, you are not interested in using the Kinect as a plain Near-IR camera, but in the end want to compress the 3D data. So I would suggest to have a look at this:

http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/compression.php

Best Georg

---

Originally posted by [Georg](https://answers.ros.org/users/171/georg/) with karma: 328 on 2012-10-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0